# Shutdown messages from encrypted volume, serious or not?

Tags: encryption, shutdown, systemd, lvm

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for a couple of months now on my computer. Installed it using the default installer with Full Disk Encryption enabled. Now, when I shutdown my computer systemd-shutdown produces these two messages:

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-0: Device or resource busy
systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize DM devices ignoring
```

They do appear consistently, also after a clean install. I experienced this with both Ubuntu and Pop_OS!. Without encryption there are no messages displayed during shutdown. In my systemd shutdown log I see the following messages popping up among others:

```
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-cryptsetup[13215]: Device nvme0n1p3_crypt is still in use.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-cryptsetup[13215]: Failed to deactivate: Device or resource busy
[......]
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@nvme0n1p3_crypt.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@nvme0n1p3_crypt.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Cryptography Setup for nvme0n1p3_crypt.
```

I've searched for a while and saw people with different kinds of linux distributions receiving these messages. The only real 'solution' I saw was suppressing the messages. My question is, is this normal behavior where the encrypted drive will eventually unmount after initial warnings or is it signalling that the unmounting didn't complete at all? I'm mainly worried about possible data corruption caused by improper unmounting. The messages themselves do not bother me.

Journalctl log from last shutdown (I replaced my username and UUID's, also missing are snappackages unmounting):

```
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot/efi...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-cryptsetup[13215]: Device nvme0n1p3_crypt is still in use.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-cryptsetup[13215]: Failed to deactivate: Device or resource busy
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for core18, revision 1988...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 66...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1514...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@nvme0n1p3_crypt.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@nvme0n1p3_crypt.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Cryptography Setup for nvme0n1p3_crypt.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-xxxxx\xxxxxx.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx-xxxx.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-vgubuntu-swap_1...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: boot.mount: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dvgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-vgubuntu-swap_1.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-vgubuntu-swap_1.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dLVM\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-dm\x2d2.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-2.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user lvm[13235]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" unmonitored
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Finished Reboot.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Reached target Reboot.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd[1]: Shutting down.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
mrt 26 19:24:52 user systemd-journald[733]: Journal stopped
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had the same error message. I have to create a "cosmetic" `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/zfs.shutdown` script with `#!/bin/sh\nzpool export -a` content, because all of my zfs mounts were unmounted by the systemd, thx... but the remained ZFS DM devices blocked the underlying LVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd-shutdown` will try to shutdown what it can. It will not be able to detach `/` so the notice is to be expected. Besides ignoring and suppressing this message there is software that avoids this but you need to replace the initramfs started so it is one of the first pieces of software used to boot the system.

> Shutdown messages from encrypted volume, serious or not?

No :)

---

If you want shutdown to be able to detach `/` you need a different "initramfs" than Ubuntu uses. [dracut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracut_(software)) can do this.

More:

- [How to install dracut on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248970/how-to-install-dracut-on-ubuntu)
- [manual page for 20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/dracut.8.html)

> Create an initramfs  for the kernel with the version . If  is omitted, then the version of the actual running kernel is used. If  is omitted or empty, then the default location /boot/initramfs-.img is used.
>
> dracut creates an initial image used by the kernel for preloading the block device modules
> (such as IDE, SCSI or RAID) which are needed to access the root filesystem, mounting the
> root filesystem and booting into the real system.
>
> At boot time, the kernel unpacks that archive into RAM disk, mounts and uses it as initial
> root file system. All finding of the root device happens in this early userspace.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! If I understand things correctly systemd-shutdown tries to detach the LVM which contains /. Therefore the LVM will not be able to be detached thus leaving us with a message. 

On a non encrypted clean install systemd-shutdown won't try to detach the file system containing / because it 'knows' that this isn't possible. 

LVM so to say obscures the detection of /?

That should explain why I don't get this message when I don't use encryption. In the end this shouldn't impact data of main volume than.

Comment: yes and the dracut project is an attempt to fix a couple issues (including this one) but it looks like it never caught on to be the default.

Comment: Okay, good to know! This clears things up.